# Performance of methods casting Object to String

Tags: java

What is the difference & performance between (ObjectClass not extend from String)

```
ObjectClass myObject = new ....
```

Method 1

```
String iString = "" + myObject;
```

Method 2 - ObjectClass not extend from String, i know it will be "ClassCastException" but assuming it's extend from String, what better ?

```
String iString = (String)myObject; //will fail?
```

Method 3

```
String iString = String.valueOf(myObject);
```

Method 4

```
String iString = myObject.toString();
```

Comment: Does `ObjectClass` extend `String`?  In all cases except for method #2 a new `String` object will be created.  And method #2 should fail if `ObjectClass` cannot be casted to a `String`.

Comment: `(String) obj` and `obj.toString()` are completely different operations. `myObject` would need to extend `String` for it to not throw a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: 1,3,4 basically all call `toString()` on your object. 2 will fail with a `ClassCastException`. All except 4 are "null-safe".

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: ObjectClass not extend from String, i know it will be "ClassCastException" but assuming it's extend from String, what better ?

Comment: Nothing can extend from String, String is final. "What is better" is a silly question, even with another class/interface as an example.

Comment: Just to answer your performance question. Method 1 is the slowest because it calls `toString` but also does unnecessary concatenation. Method 3 & 4 are nearly identical except that Method 3 does a null check before calling `toString`.